# Niimbot printer not printing - Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I have this Niimbot portable Bluetooth printer(A chinese printer). I want to use this to print stickers in my custom app.

I already tried this code:

```
public async Task Print(string devName, string image)
    {
        BluetoothDevice device = (from bd in bluetoothAdapter?.BondedDevices where bd?.Name == devName select bd).FirstOrDefault();

        try
        {
            BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            await bluetoothSocket?.ConnectAsync();

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("TEST PRINT");
            await bluetoothSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //await Task.Delay(2000);

            bluetoothSocket.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

It seems to connect to printer's bluetooth because the printer beeps everytime `bluetoothSocket?.ConnectAsync();` is called, but there is no printing happening.

Comment: Is there any log about this  problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No logs found. Printer only beeps when connected/disconnected.